# Set 0 or 1 values in SQL-Server table cells based on working hours split by 15 minutes intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datatable

I have the following datatable:

[image: Table]

The above datatable returned after the following query:

```
select 
    SeamanCode,WorkingDate,
    '' As T011,
    '' As T012,
    '' As T013,
    '' As T014,
    '' As T021,
    '' As T022 ,
    SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR,FromDate , 120),11,6 ) + ' & '  + SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR,ToDate , 120),11,6 ) as WorkingTime
from 
    SeamanWorkingHours
where 
    SeamanCode = '1323' and WorkingDate  = '2016-06-01'
```

What I want to do for example:

1. Concatenate all working time hours so that only one row will be returned. My desired table will be something like:

[image: Desired Table]

2. Set value 1 at T011 if exists substring "00:00 - 00:15" at working time column, set 0 if doesn't. T012 means that exists string "00:15 - 00:30" etc.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Can you please  it as text instead of image

Comment: This sounds like you want some sort of pivot table, except that it will be ugly with so many columns.  Could you post your desired output as text?

Comment: Don't store T011 value as calculated from other table data. Will only cause data inconsistency. Create a view instead. (Or, if SQL Server, have a computed column.)

Comment: Sorry but i dont know how to show my desired table as text....!

Comment: include some of your data sample. preferably  in query format so we could  construct a table and feed it faster

Answer (score 0):

`Group_Concat` is what you are looking for.

**Bad News** Unfortunately, MSSQL does not support it.

**Good News** We've a work around. Thanks to [Code**Plex**](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/releases/view/618110) .

**INSTRUCTION** 
You can read the documentation for better understanding, but here is a shortcut.:

1. Download the Group_Concat package from the link above.
2. Extract the content and Run the script `GroupConcatInstallation`. NOTE: you must first enable **SQL CLR Integration**(

   ```
   sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
   GO  RECONFIGURE;  
   GO  sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;  
   GO  RECONFIGURE;  
   GO
   ```

   ) before running this script.
3. That's it you are ready to use the `Group_Concat` function.

**Try this query**

```
Select 
    Distinct SeamanCode,
    (Case When 
        SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR,FromDate , 120),11,6 ) + '-'  + 
        SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR,ToDate , 120),11,6 ) = '00:00 - 00:15' Then 1 Else 0 End) As T011,
    (Case When 
        SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR,FromDate , 120),11,6 ) + '-'  + 
        SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR,ToDate , 120),11,6 ) = '00:00 - 00:15' Then 1 Else 0 End) As T011,
    (Case when TempWTime = '00:00 - 00:15' Then 1 else 0 end) as T011,
    (Case when TempWTime = '00:15 - 00:30' Then 1 else 0 end) as T012,
    dbo.Group_Concat(TempWTime) as WorkingTime) Over (Partition By   SeamanCode)
From
    SeamanWorkingHours
Where
    SeamanCode = '1323' And WorkingDate  = '2016-06-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select  distinct SeamanCode,WorkingDate,
'' As T011,
'' As T012,
'' As T013,
'' As T014,
'' As T021,
'' As T022 ,
WorkingTime = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR,FromDate , 120),11,6 ) + ' & '  + SUBSTRING( CONVERT(VARCHAR,ToDate , 120),11,6 )
          from SeamanWorkingHours 
          where SeamanCode = '1323' and WorkingDate  = '2016-06-01' 
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from SeamanWorkingHours
where SeamanCode = '1323' and WorkingDate  = '2016-06-01'
```

I managed to construct the rows concatenation on WorkingHours column.